# Submitting single page quiz answers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a one-page quiz that submits with one button and self-grades based on values in my database. Currently, I can render the exam and the results view seems to show correct logic in the controller; however, I can only choose one answer out of all answers for all questions (I believe that is due to the radio_button use) but even if I switch that to check_box it still only grades one answer. I am really trying to figure this out and it's mind-bottling (it probably doesn't help that I am completely new to this). Here is what I have.

```
<h1><%= @exam.name %></h1>
 <%= form_tag({:controller => "exams", :action => "grading"}) do %>
  <ol class="questions">
   <% @exam.questions.each do |question| %>
   <li>
   <%= question.content %>
     <ol class="answers">
     <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
      <li>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:answer, answer.id) %>
        <%= label("answer_".concat(answer.id.to_s).to_sym, answer.content) %>
      </li>
     <% end %>
     </ol>
   </li>
   <% end %>
  </ol>

  <div><%= submit_tag("Submit", :class => "submit") %></div>
```

And in the exams controller:

```
def grading
 @exam ||= Exam.find(session[:exam_id]) if session[:exam_id]
 total = @exam.questions.count.to_i

 session[:total]   = total
 session[:correct] = 0
 @total   = session[:total]

 answerid = params[:answer]
 @answer = answerid ? Answer.find(answerid) : nil


 if @answer and @answer.correct
   @correct = true
   session[:correct] += 1
 else
  @correct = false
 end

 redirect_to results_url
end

def results
  @correct = session[:correct]
  @total   = session[:total]

  @score = @correct * 100 / @total
end
```

I apologize if things look a bit pieced together and rather basic... they are. I appreciate any ideas on how to achieve my goals. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:answer, answer.id) %>
```

As it's set up now all your radio buttons belong to the same group, you need to change the first attribute to something different for each question I think. Maybe something like:

```
<%= radio_button_tag("answer_for_#{question.id}", answer.id) %>
```

Then each question will have its own batch of answers and you can find which question it belongs to.

#### Update

I haven't tried the following, so not sure if it will work, but try changing it to:

```
radio_button_tag("answer[#{question.id}]", answer.id)
```

Then see if `params[:answer]` returns a hash which you can iterate over and extract all the answers from.

Comment: <%= radio_button_tag("answer_for_#{question.id}", answer.id) %> This line definitely made is so that I can submit multiple radio buttons and my dev log says "answer_for_2"=>"4", "answer_for_4"=>"8", "answer_for_5"=>"9", "commit"=>"Submit"} but now I need to make the grading logic work. Any ideas?

Comment: I had to learn about working with hashes from the api docs but that worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: I apologize but I can't upvote because I am brand new. I would if I could

Answer (score 2):

For anyone searching this later, I did the above updated answer along with this in the controller:

```
h = params[:answer]

h.values.each do |answer|
  @answer = answer ? Answer.find(answer) : nil


  if @answer and @answer.correct
    @correct = true
    session[:correct] += 1
  else
    @correct = false
  end
end
```

Comment: By the way, if you're iterating over the answers, `@correct` will be set to the last answer's value. Do you need it? Maybe `session[:correct] += 1 if @answer and @answer.correct` is enough?

Comment: This is my first app and I am learning as I go, so it is entirely probable that there is a lot of extra code. I will definitely try that though when I decide to refactor. Thanks!